# Unable to get Groovy working with GCP Libraries

Tags: groovy, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to integrate Groovy with GCP Java Libraries, but it's constantly complaining about missing GCP JAR libraries.

My Groovy code is:

```
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;

class GroovyExample {

    String format(Integer i) { 
        System.out.println(i.toString());
        return i.toString();
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        assert format('String') == 'String';
        assert new GroovyExample().format(Integer.valueOf(1)) == '1';
    }
}
```

The command I use to run Groovy is:

```
groovy -cp ./usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/java-managed-vm/appengine-java-vmruntime GroovyExample.groovy
```

It'd be of great help to get through the solution to run this Groovy script.

Just to add more and for further reference, am trying to run this in customized Docker container that I've created involving both GCP and Groovy. Below is the file.

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:latest
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget unzip
CMD ["groovysh"]
ENV GROOVY_HOME /opt/groovy
ENV GROOVY_VERSION 2.5.2
RUN set -o errexit -o nounset \
    && echo "Downloading Groovy" \
    && wget --output-document=groovy.zip "https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/groovy/${GROOVY_VERSION}/distribution/apache-groovy-binary-${GROOVY_VERSION}.zip" \
    \
    && echo "Importing keys listed in http://www.apache.org/dist/groovy/KEYS from key server" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && for key in \
        "7FAA0F2206DE228F0DB01AD741321490758AAD6F" \
        "331224E1D7BE883D16E8A685825C06C827AF6B66" \
        "34441E504A937F43EB0DAEF96A65176A0FB1CD0B" \
        "9A810E3B766E089FFB27C70F11B595CEDC4AEBB5" \
        "81CABC23EECA0790E8989B361FF96E10F0E13706" \
    ; do \
        for server in \
            "ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net" \
            "hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80" \
            "pgp.mit.edu" \
        ; do \
            echo "  Trying ${server}"; \
            if gpg --keyserver "${server}" --recv-keys "${key}"; then \
                break; \
            fi; \
        done; \
    done; \
    if [ $(gpg --list-keys | grep -c "pub ") -ne 5 ]; then \
        echo "ERROR: Failed to fetch GPG keys" >&2; \
        exit 1; \
    fi \
    \
    && echo "Checking download signature" \
    && wget --no-verbose --output-document=groovy.zip.asc "https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/groovy/${GROOVY_VERSION}/distribution/apache-groovy-binary-${GROOVY_VERSION}.zip.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --verify groovy.zip.asc groovy.zip \
    && rm --recursive --force "${GNUPGHOME}" \
    && rm groovy.zip.asc \
    \
    && echo "Installing Groovy" \
    && unzip groovy.zip \
    && rm groovy.zip \
    && mv "groovy-${GROOVY_VERSION}" "${GROOVY_HOME}/" \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/grape" /usr/bin/grape \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovy" /usr/bin/groovy \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovyc" /usr/bin/groovyc \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovyConsole" /usr/bin/groovyConsole \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovydoc" /usr/bin/groovydoc \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovysh" /usr/bin/groovysh \
    && ln --symbolic "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/java2groovy" /usr/bin/java2groovy \
    \
    && echo "Adding groovy user and group" \
    && groupadd --system --gid 1000 groovy \
    && useradd --system --gid groovy --uid 1000 --shell /bin/bash --create-home groovy \
    && mkdir --parents /home/groovy/.groovy/grapes \
    && chown --recursive groovy:groovy /home/groovy \
    \
    && echo "Symlinking root .groovy to groovy .groovy" \
    && ln -s /home/groovy/.groovy /root/.groovy
```

Am running above command using command:

```
docker run -ti 8332026e2ddf bash
```

where

> 8332026e2ddf

is ID of my image.

Comment: Do you know which libraries it is asking for? Have you been able to deploy before with the same configs?

Comment: Btw why dont u use official groovy:2.5.2 docker image ? link: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/groovy/

Comment: @anon - it's simply failing for com.google.cloud.storage.Blob

Comment: @rgrebski - can do that, but i need to integrate Groovy in gcloud docker image; hence the above approach.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but GCP has separate client libraries so have you tried adding the GCS library as described here?
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java